# “Stuff happen” or “stuff happens”?

Tags: verbs, subjects

Is it “bad stuff *happens* to good people” or “bad stuff *happen* to good people”?

Comment: Why does God let “bad stuff **happen** to good people”? "Stuff happens."

Answer (score 1):

*Stuff* is a mass noun and doesn't take the plural form of the verbs. So in your case *happens* seems to be the correct choice. Here are some other examples that may further clarify the usage:

> This stuff is great.
>
> All my stuff is in the suitcase.

Answer (score 0):

“Bad stuff happens to good people.” *Stuff* is singular, and so the verb must also be singular.